# php synatax what do these do? '^' and '|'

Tags: php, syntax, operands

IN php, how do the following operands work?

^
|

e.g. `$a =  11;
$b =    7;
echo $a ^ $b;`

outputs 12

and

```
    $a =    11;
$b =    7;
echo $a | $b;
```

outputs 15

Im not sure why in each case. Can someone please shed some light?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: Whats with the down votes? I get that this has been asked before, but unless I knew to look for bitwise operators this would have been impossible to search for. If you are down voting please leave a reasonable explanation for doing so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are bitwise [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) and [OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR).

```
$a = 11; // 1011
$b =  7; // 0111
```

With **XOR** each bit that is different in `$a` and `$b` becomes a `1`, the bits that are the same become a `0`.

```
$a ^ $b: // 1100 = 12
```

With **OR** each bit that is a `1` in either `$a` or `$b` becomes a `1`, in this case all the bits.

```
$a | $b: // 1111 = 15
```

There is also an **AND** equivalent: `$a & $b: // 0011 = 3`

[A full list of PHP's bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)[.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop)

Answer (score 3):

They are bitwise operators.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Basically these are used for binary data. These are used quite often to combine a series of flags within a single integer. For instance, if I had two flags:

```
FLAG1 = (binary)'1' = (integer)1
FLAG2 = (binary)'10' = (integer)2
```

I could combine the two using a bitwise operator:

```
$combined_flags = FLAG1 | FLAG2 = (binary)'11' = (integer)3
```

Then I could check if one of the flags is set using a bitwise operator as well:

```
if ($combined_flags & FLAG1) echo 'flag 1 is set to true.';
```

Answer (score 0):

They are bitwise operators, this means they operate on binary numbers.

`11` is `1011` in binary, and `7` is `0111`.

`^` is `XOR`.  For each bit in both values, it returns 1 if they are different.

```
11 ^ 7 = 1011 ^ 0111 = 1100 = 12
```

`|` is `OR`.  For each bit in both values, it returns 1 if at least one is 1.

```
11 | 7 = 1011 | 0111 = 1111 = 15
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php